# Lista com todos ícones do Material Icons

Tags: html5, html-select, material-design

Bom dia, Galera!

Estou criando um formulário com SELECT onde os OPTION são ícones do Material Icons:

```
<option data-icon="case" value="case">case</option>
<option data-icon="favorite" value="favorite">favorite</option>
```

Existe algum maluco que já fez essa lista com mais de 900 ícones?
Não precisa ser idêntica, apenas algo para facilitar.

Já fiz 89, mas desde já agradeço!

Comment: Já procurou ni Git deles? https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, encontrei uma lista em: https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/blob/master/iconfont/codepoints